# fatal error: Imlib2.h: No such file or directory, But I have this file

Tags: c++, c++11, eclipse-cdt, x11

I have installed imlib2-1.4.5 and I have the file in /usr/local/lib path. Also I have created softlink for this package.
When I use this in my project and load in eclipse ide, The above fatal error is found while compiling.
I set the project settings with /usr/local/lib path also, but still I find the same mistake.
I request your help to solve my problem. Thanks everyone in advance.

Comment: you have lmlib2.h in /usr/local/lib? thats what /usr/local/include is for.
make sure that you have the header-file in there, and set your include-directory correct in eclipse. make sure that your compile-command then has sth like "-I/usr/local/include" in it

Answer (score 1):

Usually a library and its development package are separate unless you compiled and deployed it yourself.  `/usr/local/lib` is path for binary file which would be part of binary package. Header file goes to include folder and is installed by `imlib2-devel-1.4.5`